# Closure, open, and closed sets.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $A = \{\frac{n}{n+1}\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$. Find $\overline{A}$, $int(A)$, $\partial A$, and $A'$.

I can find $A'$ (closed set) and the interior, but not so sure about the closure and whatever $\partial A$ means (limit point?). The closure of the set is the smallest closed set containing $A$. Well, it isn't open since we can make an epsilon ball around each point in the set and not be in the set. The compliment isn't open so it isn't closed either...confusion.

Comment: Why not look at your text long enough to determine the meaning of $\partial A$; that'll convince others it's worth spending time to answer. Also: not every set is either open or closed. Consider the subset $0 \le x < 1$ of $\mathbb R$; it's neither open nor closed. (It's also possible for a set to be both open *and* closed. In short: your usual intuition about the words "open" and "closed" is pretty useless here, alas.)

Comment: A set is closed if its compliment is open. A set is open if we can make an epsilon ball around each point in the set and remain in the set. A non-topological definition.

Comment: Well, we agree about the metric definition of open and closed.

Comment: usually $\partial A$ means the boundary of A, i.e. the points which lie in both the closure of $A$ and in the closure of its complement. this may also be defined as the points which lie in the closure of $A$ but not in the interior of $A$

Comment: Does a boundry point mean the same thing as a $\textit{limit point}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**: The numbers in $A$ 
$$A=\left\lbrace\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{3},\ldots, \frac{n}{n+1},\dots\right\rbrace$$ grow arbitrarily close to $L=1$. So, a good start would be to examine the set $$A\cup \{1\}$$ and ask (among others) the questions

1. Is there a sequence in $A$ that converges to a point outside $A$?
2. Is there a sequence in $A$ that converges to a point outside $A\cup\{1\}$?
3. How is an interior point defined? Do the points in $A$ satisfy this condition?

Answer (score 0):

Consider the set $U=(1,\infty)\cup(-\infty,1/2)\cup(1/2,2/3)\cup(2/3,3/4)\cup\ldots$. $U$ is open because it is the union of open sets, and $A\cup U=\Bbb R-\{1\}$. That is, $U^c=A\cup\{1\}$ is closed. Furthermore, no open neighbourhood of $1$ is disjoint to $A$. Then, $\overline A=A\cup\{1\}$.

$A$ does not contain any interval, so its interior is empty.

$\partial A$  is the border of $A$, that is
$$\partial A=\overline A\cap \overline{A^c}=(A\cup\{1\})\cap\overline {U\cup\{1\}}=(A\cup\{1\})\cap\Bbb R=A\cup\{1\}$$

Answer (score 0):

The set $A=\{1-1/(n+1)\}_{n=1}^\infty$ The sequence $\{1-1/(n+1)\}$ converges to 1.So 1 is a limi point of $A$. $\overline{\rm A}=A\cup 1$.$A$ has empty interior as points of $A$ are discrete.So $\delta A =\overline{\rm A}\setminus A^ \circ=\overline{\rm A}$